# Bender Theme on OSClass.org Search Sidebar Issues

Tags: search, themes, sidebar, osclass

I have chosen osclass.org over many popular listing/directory scripts and so far it looks very promising.

As a newbie to osclass I'm facing this little error concerning search-sidebar.php in Bender themes.

This error occurs only when I click on one of the locations on the home page.
The error is:
Warning: Illegal string offset 'fk_i_parent_id' in E:\SERVER-BACKUP\EasyPHP-12.1\www\MyWebSite\osclass\oc-content\themes\bender\search-sidebar.php on line 74.

Line 74 in search-sidebar.php:

```
<?php $parentSelected=false; if (in_array(osc_category_id(), osc_search_category()) || in_array(osc_categ2ory_slug()."/", osc_search_category()) || in_array(osc_category_slug(), osc_search_category()) || count(osc_search_category())==0 || $category['fk_i_parent_id'] == osc_category_id()){ $parentSelected=true;} ?>
```

I would be very if anyone advice me how solve this issue.

Comment: Are you sur $category is an array and not a string?

Comment: I really don't know because the theme was developed by osclass. And because of that I don't know where to start. I also placed a topic on their Forum.

Answer (score 1):

Please, replace

```
$category['fk_i_parent_id'] == osc_category_id()
```

with

```
(isset($category['fk_i_parent_id]) && $category['fk_i_parent_id'] == osc_category_id())
```

do not forget the "(" and ")"

If should be something like this

```
<?php $parentSelected=false; if (in_array(osc_category_id(), osc_search_category()) || in_array(osc_categ2ory_slug()."/", osc_search_category()) || in_array(osc_category_slug(), osc_search_category()) || count(osc_search_category())==0 || (isset($category['fk_i_parent_id]) && $category['fk_i_parent_id'] == osc_category_id())){ $parentSelected=true;} ?>
```